# How to create a clustered index when using code-first migration with Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations, clustered-index

I have a `MessageModel` with a timestamp attribute of when the message was created. I would like to make a clustered index on this long attribute. I hope to achieve a query speed-up when doing a query to get all messages newer than a certain timestamp. The timestamp value is never changed after creation. I currently have a regular index on a int `Id` attribute.

How can I add a clustered index on a models attribute using Entity Framework code-first migration in ASP.NET MVC 4.5?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE**: EntityFramework 6.1 introduced the `[Index]` attribute which can be used to specify an index on an arbitrary field.  Example:

```
public class MessageModel 
{
    [Index(IsClustered = true, IsUnique = false)]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

For older versions of Entity Framework, I will leave my original answer below:

Unfortunately EF [doesn't really provide much support for indexes](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/57).  The best way to approach this depends on the type of migrations you're doing.  If you're not using automatic migrations and you want to add an index to a NEW table (i.e. one you have a migration for), then you can modify the generated CreateTable statement in the migration to add indexes.  This technique is used in [one of the Entity Framework tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) (search for Index to find it)

If you *are* using automatic migrations (or the table already exists) then you can still use old-style SQL to create your index - generate a migration, then modify your code to include a plain old `CREATE INDEX` statement.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. You basically answered what I was starting to fear, but I guess I will manage to call a CREATE INDEX and take it from there :)

Comment: This feature has been added to Entity Framework 6.1.